# Reaction energies of solids from quantum chemistry?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, software, free-energy

I was reading a paper by Catlow et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.2010.0111)], and they mentioned the dissolution of copper into copper ions, which is given by this equation:

> $$\ce{Cu2O(s) + 2 h+ <=> Cu+(aq) + 1/2 O2(g)} \tag{2.5}$$

where $\ce{h+}$  is a hole.

I am wondering whether it is possible to calculate the free energy of this reaction using quantum chemistry software? And which software will be able to perform this? I believe that this is not possible using periodic DFT due to the presence of charged ions.

#### References

1. Catlow, C. R. A.; Guo, Z. X.; Miskufova, M.; Shevlin, S. A.; Smith, A. G. H.; Sokol, A. A.; Walsh, A.; Wilson, D. J.; Woodley, S. M. Advances in Computational Studies of Energy Materials. *Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences* **2010**, 368 (1923), 3379–3456. DOI: [10.1098/rsta.2010.0111](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.2010.0111).

Comment: Ad 1, you equation is not clear and not in line with your text. Ad 2 the answer to the question is strongly depend on what accuracy you need, what effects you want consider etc.

Comment: @koroma Thank you, I corrected the reference (we are using ACS style whenever possible) and the equation number. In the paper the reaction you provided is labeled under (2.5), not (2.4). I also tweaked formatting a little so that the symbol for a hole is upright and easily recognizable. If you are interested in further details, please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.